# Compare Strings separated by Comma in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #COMPANY_CHANGE 
        (       
        Risk_ID VARCHAR(50),
        LINKED_COMPANIES VARCHAR(MAX),
        PERIOD VARCHAR(20)

-- Populate the #COMPANY_CHANGE 
)

INSERT INTO #COMPANY_CHANGE (Risk_ID, LINKED_COMPANIES,PERIOD)
VALUES(1, 'X,y,z', 202202),
        (1, 'X,y', 202208),
        (2, 'A,B,C', 202202),
        (2, 'B,C,D', 202208),
      (4,'Z',202202),
      (4,'Z',202208)
```

So for each Risk_ID I am trying to compare LINKED_COMPANIES from Start Period=202202 with the endperiod =202208, for instance for Risk_ID=1 we have 3 companies linked on 202202 which is X,y,z but in the end period 202208 we only have two companies which is X,y which means company z was removed

My desired output should be something like

```
Risk_ID  PERIOD   Change  Company_Added Company_Removed
1         202208   Yes       Null               z
2         202208   Yes       D                  A
4         202208   No        NUll               Null
```

here is my code:

```
WITH CompanyChanges AS (
  SELECT
    RISK_ID,
    PERIOD,
    LINKED_COMPANIES,
    LAG(LINKED_COMPANIES) OVER (PARTITION BY RISK_ID ORDER BY PERIOD) AS PREVIOUS_LINKED_COMPANIES
  FROM COMPANY_CHANGE
)
SELECT
  RISK_ID,
  PERIOD,
  STRING_AGG(REPLACE(LINKED_COMPANIES, PREVIOUS_LINKED_COMPANIES, ''), ',') AS Change
FROM CompanyChanges
WHERE PREVIOUS_LINKED_COMPANIES IS NOT NULL AND PREVIOUS_LINKED_COMPANIES <> LINKED_COMPANIES
GROUP BY RISK_ID, PERIOD
ORDER BY RISK_ID, PERIOD;
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: @DaleK What do you mean?

Comment: please add the query and data in db-fiddle and post it.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Here's a thought... how can you avoid the need to search comma-delimited lists of things by fixing your data model?

Comment: I mean don't add clarifications as comments, edit your question and improve it.

Comment: @JoyNa :               https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mYim9ESsHtAqncCDqibtBA/1#&togetherjs=sn3JpibF6U

Comment: how is that your making sense in the SQL query which is a `starting period` and `ending period`

Comment: @KhutsoMphelo: When providing a dbfiddle, and asking about sql-server, Please also provide the dbfidde for sql-server, and not some not working MySQL variant.  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/GV2pX9Tl )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution is based on `LAG()` analytic function and `STRING_SPLIT()` with appropriate joins. This approach returns all periods, which have history:

```
SELECT 
   t.Risk_ID,
   t.PERIOD,
   Company_Added = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(s1.[value], ',')
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(LINKED_COMPANIES1, ',') s1
      LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(LINKED_COMPANIES2, ',') s2 ON s1.[value] = s2.[value]
      WHERE s2.[value] IS NULL
   ),
   Company_Removed = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(s2.[value], ',')
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(LINKED_COMPANIES2, ',') s2
      LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(LINKED_COMPANIES1, ',') s1 ON s2.[value] = s1.[value]
      WHERE s1.[value] IS NULL
  )
FROM (  
   SELECT 
      Risk_ID, 
      PERIOD, 
      LINKED_COMPANIES1 = LINKED_COMPANIES, 
      LINKED_COMPANIES2 = LAG(LINKED_COMPANIES) OVER (PARTITION BY Risk_ID ORDER BY PERIOD)
   FROM #COMPANY_CHANGE
) t
WHERE t.LINKED_COMPANIES2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.Risk_ID, t.PERIOD
```

Result (for all available periods):

| Risk_ID | PERIOD | Company_Added | Company_Removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202208 | *null* | z |
| 2 | 202208 | D | A |
| 4 | 202208 | *null* | *null* |

Comment: Thank you, it works as well. I just need to filter out the Starting Period that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit tricky, one potential solution is:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *
    ,   lag(linked_companies) OVER(partition BY risk_id ORDER BY period) AS prev_companies
    FROM    #COMPANY_CHANGE c
)
SELECT  risk_id, period
,   MAX(CASE WHEN a.value = prevvalue THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS changed
,   STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN a.value = a.prevvalue THEN NULL ELSE a.value END, ',') within GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS added
,   STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN a.value = a.prevvalue THEN NULL ELSE a.prevvalue END, ',') within GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS removed
FROM    cte
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  curr.value
        ,   prev.value AS prevValue
        FROM    STRING_SPLIT(LINKED_COMPANIES, ',') curr
        FULL JOIN STRING_SPLIT(prev_companies, ',') prev
            ON  prev.value = curr.value
    ) a
WHERE prev_companies IS NOT NULL --Remove period without history
GROUP BY risk_id, period
```

The main idea is to use FULL JOIN to get both sides of the story, the newly added and removed.

By using STRING_SPLIT, we get one company per row. By FULL JOIN, we get NULL on left side if a company was deleted, and NULL on right side if company was added.

`CASE WHEN a.value = a.prevvalue THEN NULL ELSE a.value END` generates NULL if no changes occured, otherwise it displays added value since previous row.
`CASE WHEN a.value = a.prevvalue THEN NULL ELSE a.prevvalue END` does the same, but switches values around, and generates the removed.

Finally, i aggregate the changes back by using STRING_AGG.

Output:

| risk_id | period | changed | added | removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202208 | 1 | NULL | z |
| 2 | 202208 | 1 | D | A |
| 4 | 202208 | 0 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Brilliant!!! This works exactly how I wanted it. Thank you :)

Comment: can you post it with a demo on [db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/_EZjM-du). Did try with your code, threw some error.

Comment: @JoyNa you're running fiddle with mysql, it doesn't have same syntax.

Comment: I understand here is the link [https://dbfiddle.uk/hEqD-VRR](https://dbfiddle.uk/hEqD-VRR)